# Cannot add sqlite entry using PHP

Tags: php, python, sqlite

I have a database that has a table. I have written a simple python program to write to the database as follows.

```
 import sqlite3
 import sys
 arg = sys.argv
 handle= sqlite3.connect('new_test.db')
 print "Opened database successfully";
 print type(arg[1]), arg[2] 
 handle.execute("INSERT INTO RECORD (ID,NAME,PROJECT,) \
    VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" %(str(arg[1]), str(arg[2]),str 
 (arg[3]));
 print "after execute"
 handle.commit()
print "Records created successfully";
handle.close()
```

This works fine from the command line `python insert.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Now I am doing the same from a php code as:

```
$data=shell_exec("python insert.py $id $name $project").
```

It does not add entries to the table. The execution stops near `handle.execute`

- checked from print statements. What should I change or alter ?

Is it because of some permissions or do I have to add anything ?
Note: the entries are not duplicate

EDIT:Some additional things I tried which could be useful:

1. I tried to call the script via PHP but added static string arguments to the database. It still didnt go through.
2. I commented out the `handle.execute()` from the python program, the program now executes till the end.
   So the problem is due to that instruction.
3. checked the environment variables and python modules, They are as expected.

Comment: You are able to operate with SQLite without python... is it a mandatory part? And compare first that the command is the same.

Comment: @FieryCat Yes sqlite can be done with PHP too. But I am more comfortable with python. and which command exactly ?

Comment: Are you running the PHP script from the command line or via web request?

Comment: from the web page

Comment: I don't know python, but this looks wonky `handle.execute("INSERT INTO RECORD (ID,NAME,PROJECT,) \
    VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(str(arg[1]), str(arg[2]),str 
 (arg[3]));` Looks like a `printf()` syntax, but you only pass 3 args and specify 3 columns but have 4 `%s` and then tack on 3 args for some reason.

Comment: @AbraCadaver changed it, sorry I pasted it incorrectly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax, but looks incorrect: `VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" %(str(arg[1]), str(arg[2]),str 
 (arg[3])`.  You are at least missing a comma between the SQL and the list of args, and I have only ever seen the `:something` or `?` placeholders.

Comment: There will not be a comma between VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')"' and  '%(str(arg[1]), str(arg[2]),str (arg[3])"'

Comment: What is a link to the docs for the `execute()` method?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

Try next one:

```
$pdo = new \PDO('sqlite:new_test.db');
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO RECORD (ID, NAME, PROJECT)
    VALUES (:id, :name, :project)");
$query->execute(array(
    ':id' => $id, 
    ':name' => $name, 
    ':project' => $project
));
```

Comment: Try to play with permissions `chmod -R 777 new_test.db`... and be sure that DB-file wasn't opened by any other application

Comment: The db python and php file have all permissions. Also the script closes the database after commit so it should not be open